# how to get count no result or result is 0 then count is 0 else 1 in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with a SQL Server query. I want to count the number of  records between 2018-10-18 and 2018-10-28 that have non-0 values. If there are records in the date range that have value(s) of 0, the count should be 0. Here's a record that should not be counted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sno](
    [Flag] [int] NULL
) 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sno] ([Flag]) VALUES (0)
GO
```

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT  count(case when value=0  or  isnull(value,0)=0 then 0  else 1 end )Flag
  FROM [ab].[dbo].[sno]
  where getdate() between '2018-10-18' and '2018-10-28'
```

When I run this query, I get the following results:
If Flag value is 0, then I get

```
Flag
0
```

If there are no records, then I get

```
Flag
0
```

If Flag value is 1, then I get

```
Flag 
1
```

Expected result:

If there are no records or the value is 0 then I should get

```
Flag
0
```

Otherwise I should get

```
Flag 
1
```

Comment: 0 is still a valid value, so gets counted.  To avoid counting, return null; e.g. `count(case when value = 0 then null else value end)` or ``count(case when value != 0 then value end)``

Comment: Does your table have a date column? Because `GETDATE()` returns the current date and time. It doesn't seem very useful to have a `WHERE` condition here that says  `GETDATE() BETWEEN '2018-10-18' AND '2018-10-28'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways.

First way uses `COUNT()`. `COUNT()` will consider any non-NULL value in its aggregation, so we need to change the `THEN` of the `CASE` statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
Flag = COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN value = 0 OR ISNULL(value, 0) = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE 1
             END )
FROM ab.dbo.sno
WHERE
    GETDATE() BETWEEN '2018-10-18' AND '2018-10-28'
```

But wait!
You can also accomplish the same thing using `SUM()` and your original syntax, like this:

```
SELECT 
Flag = SUM(CASE WHEN value = 0 OR ISNULL(value, 0) = 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
         END)
FROM ab.dbo.sno
WHERE
    GETDATE() BETWEEN '2018-10-18' AND '2018-10-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://rextester.com/UGL6377

```
SELECT case when zeros>0 then 0 else total end from (
SELECT  sum(case when flag=0 then 1  else 0 end ) zeros, count(flag) total
  FROM  [sno]
  where getdate() between '2018-10-18' and '2018-10-28') q
```